# Java Math Exercise Not Giving Right Answer

Tags: java, math

```
7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000) + Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5))
```

What does this equal in Java I can't plug it in because if I compile it in a class/method it gives me errors even when it checks to be good. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I am getting 10.171 and more numbers but it still says I'm wrong online on my practice - it. I know 7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000) ultimately equals 8 but I just mess up on the last part of adding cause I'm not exactly sure of the value when Math.E is to the power of 5 and log.

Comment: I ran it here: http://ideone.com/EoXlmD.  It gave the output of 7.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @sid and when I run it, the output is `13.0`

Comment: It should be 13 if math works... 7 - 2 + 3 + 5 = 13

Comment: exit code for process is 1. keeps giving me this. And yes the answer is 13.0 but I still don't know why or how. Isn't Math.E something like 2.7 ~~~~~

Comment: share your whole code.

Comment: It might be your JVM. Java programs themselves generally don't give those kind of errors. Or it might be your program.

Comment: You should get a result close to 13 regardless, it may not be exactly 13, it may be something like 13.99995 or something like that but it _should_ be very close to 13 regardless.

Comment: log and pow(Math.E, x) are inverse functions, so that part should just evaluate to 5. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm

Comment: ^ ahh forgot about the inverses of them

Comment: @Jared I'd be very surprised if it gave me 13.99995.  On the other hand, 12.99995 wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: @ajb Yeah you are right, my hyperbole is wrong...it should asymptote to 13--_not_ 14 like I stated.

Comment: As written, I get `13.0`.  But I get `10.171472409516259` if I happen to use `Math.log10(Math.pow(Math.E, 5))` for the last term instead of `Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `final` part is *not* the problem:

```
public class MathCode {
    public static final double x1 = 7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000)
            + Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5));
    public static double x2 = 7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000)
            + Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5));
    private static double x3 = 7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000)
            + Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5));

    private final double x4 = 7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000)
            + Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5));
    public final double x5 = 7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000)
            + Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5));
    private double x6 = 7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000)
            + Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5));
    public double x7 = 7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000) + Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5));

    public static void main(String... args) {
        final MathCode mathCode = new MathCode();
        final double x8 = 7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000)
                + Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5));
        double x9 = 7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000) + Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5));
        System.out.println("x1: " + x1);
        System.out.println("x2: " + x2);
        System.out.println("x3: " + x3);
        System.out.println("x4: " + mathCode.x4);
        System.out.println("x5: " + mathCode.x5);
        System.out.println("x6: " + mathCode.x6);
        System.out.println("x7: " + mathCode.x7);
        System.out.println("x8: " + x8);
        System.out.println("x9: " + x9);
    }
}
```

The result of the following is:

```
x1: 13.0
x2: 13.0
x3: 13.0
x4: 13.0
x5: 13.0
x6: 13.0
x7: 13.0
x8: 13.0
x9: 13.0
```

Comment: yea I forgot when making my method having "final" before double in there and it ran now.

Comment: `final` isn't the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This ran and gave the output of 13

```
public class MathTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.print( 7 - 2 + Math.log10(1000) + Math.log(Math.pow(Math.E, 5)) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Math.exp(5)` instead of `Math.pow(Math.E,5)`

Comment: I agree that's preferrable but it's not the problem (not that I'm claiming my answer addressed whatever the problem was either).